# Highlighting words in RichEditBox

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

It is needed to highlight by fiven colour a substring in the document RichEditBox. For this purpose I wrote a method:

```
private async Task ChangeTextColor(string text, Color color)
{
    string textStr;
    bool theEnd = false;
    int startTextPos = 0;
    myRichEdit.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out textStr);

    while (theEnd == false)
    {
        myRichEdit.Document.GetRange(startTextPos, textStr.Length).GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out textStr);
        var isFinded = myRichEdit.Document.GetRange(startTextPos, textStr.Length).FindText(text, textStr.Length, FindOptions.None);

        if (isFinded != 0)
        {
            string textStr2;
            textStr2 = myRichEdit.Document.Selection.Text;

            var dialog = new MessageDialog(textStr2);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();

            myRichEdit.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor = color;
            startTextPos = myRichEdit.Document.Selection.EndPosition;
            myRichEdit.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();
        }
        else
        {
            theEnd = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

In the debugger you can see that there is a substring and isFinded is equal with the number of signs (or symbols) in the found substring. It means the fragment is found and judging by the description of the method FindText should be highlighted but it isn't. In textStr2 an empty line returns and, correspondingly, the colour doesn't change. I cannot identify the reasons of the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you postted did not set the selection, so the  `myRichEdit.Document.Selection` is null. You can use [`ITextRange.SetRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Text.ITextRange.SetRange);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to set the selection. And you can use [`ITextRange.FindText method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Text.ITextRange.FindText);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to find the string in the selection.

For example:

```
private void ChangeTextColor(string text, Color color)
{
    string textStr;

    myRichEdit.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out textStr);

    var myRichEditLength = textStr.Length;

    myRichEdit.Document.Selection.SetRange(0, myRichEditLength);
    int i = 1;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        i = myRichEdit.Document.Selection.FindText(text, myRichEditLength, FindOptions.Case);

        ITextSelection selectedText = myRichEdit.Document.Selection;
        if (selectedText != null)
        {
            selectedText.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```