# How to change background color of a custom span?

Tags: c#, uwp, richtextblock

I have a `RichTextBlock` that contains some custom `Span`. I want when `Right-Tapped` event fired I change the `Background` color of that span. I can access to that `span` but It doesn't have `Background` property.

how can I do it?

Comment: Any updates? Did my answer solve you problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Background` property in `RichTextBlock` and `Span` that we can not set the `Background` to the `Span`.

If you want the Span has "background", you should be able to add `Grid` or `StackPanel` in the [`InlineUIContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.documents.inlineuicontainer.aspx).

For example:

```
<RichTextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Paragraph>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Grid Background="Blue">
                <RichTextBlock>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Span>This is
                            <Bold>mixed content</Bold> with multiple text areas
                            <Italic>and inlines</Italic> .
                        </Span>
                    </Paragraph>
                </RichTextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
        <Span>This is
            <Bold>mixed content</Bold> with multiple text areas
            <Italic>and inlines</Italic> .
        </Span>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Also the `RichTextBlock` is used to show the data, if you want to edit the text, you should be able to use [`RichEditBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx).

Then we should be able to use `ITextRange.CharacterFormat.BackgroundColor` to change the background of the Text. There is a similar case in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634345/highlighting-words-in-richeditbox), please refer it.